# ¿Como detecto una tecla presionada en HTML5?

Tags: html, html5

Existe alguna manera de detectar las teclas presionadas en HTML5, ya que con unos amigos estoy programando una pagina web pero queremos que al apretar un boton suene un sonido.

Comment: con javascript... pero para poder solicitar ayuda acá, debes mostrar que tienes, que has intentado, y explicar el resto... lee [ask] para saber mas detalles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues en HTML, hasta donde yo sé, no.

Tendrás que tirar de JavaScript sí o sí.

Te dejo un ejemplo sencillo.

```js
function press(event) {
  alert(`Respuesta a la tecla ${event.key}`);
}
```

```html
<html onkeyup="press(event)"><h3>Pulsa aquí y después una tecla.</h3></html>
```

Evidentemente, esto es un ejemplo mínimo. No estamos aquí para programar tu página, pero si te podemos guiar.